# What is the correct wdsaveformat for .dot and .dotx?

Tags: c#, ms-word

I can´t find the correct `wdsaveformat` enumeration so I can save a document as a `.dot` or `.dotx` file.
In the code I am showing here I am saving the document as `a.docx` file.

```
docx.SaveAs2(newfilename, MSWord.WdSaveFormat.wdFormatDocumentDefault);
```

Comment: I thought you just changed it to dot or dotx as a file extensions

Comment: @freefaller He is using the namespace `Microsoft.Office.Tools.Word` from assembly: `Microsoft.Office.Tools.Word.v4.0.Utilities.dll`

Comment: And this is the relevant enum: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vba/api/word.wdsaveformat

Answer (score 3, accepted):

According to the [**documentation**](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/microsoft.office.interop.word.wdsaveformat?view=word-pia), to save a document in a template format, you may use one of the following enumerations:

> ```
> wdFormatXMLTemplate    14     XML template format.
>
> wdFormatTemplate       1      Microsoft Word template format.
>
> wdFormatTemplate97     1      Word 97 template format.
> ```

So, for `.dotx`, you may use `wdFormatXMLTemplate` and for `.dot`, you may use either `wdFormatTemplate` or `wdFormatTemplate97`.

Answer (score 2):

Starting with Office 2007, the default document file format is DOCX.
[From the docs](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/microsoft.office.interop.word.wdsaveformat?view=word-pia):

> `wdFormatDocumentDefault` 16
>   Word default document file format. For Microsoft Office Word 2007, this is the DOCX format.

If you want to use DOTX, you have to select `wdFormatTemplate`:

> `wdFormatTemplate` 1
>   Microsoft Word template format.

```
docx.SaveAs2(newfilename, MSWord.WdSaveFormat.wdFormatTemplate);
```